# How to get a column derived from joining on inserted value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For the following example I set shipping method to 'UPS'

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer] (CustomerID int primary key, ShipMethodRef INT)

INSERT INTO  [dbo].[Customer] VALUES (5497, 20);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].ShipMethod(ShipMethodID int PRIMARY KEY, Name varchar(10));

INSERT INTO  [dbo].ShipMethod VALUES (20, 'Fedex'), (21, 'UPS')


UPDATE [dbo].[Customer]  
set ShipMethodRef = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ShipMethodID from [dbo].[ShipMethod]
                         WHERE [dbo].[ShipMethod].Name = 'UPS') 
                    THEN (SELECT ShipMethodID from [dbo].[ShipMethod] 
                         WHERE [dbo].[ShipMethod].Name = 'UPS')
                    ELSE curTable.ShipMethodRef END
OUTPUT ShipMethod.Name as ShipMethodName
FROM [dbo].[Customer] curTable 
JOIN [dbo].ShipMethod ShipMethod ON curTable.ShipMethodRef = ShipMethod.ShipMethodID
WHERE CustomerID=5497;
```

The `OUTPUT` clause returns `Fedex` - How can I change it to reflect the post insert state that the customer's shipping method is 'UPS' (as their shipping method Id is now 21)?

Comment: I think I've figured out what you need now. You want to return the value of `SELECT ShipMethod.Name FROM ShipMethod WHERE ShipMethodRef = 21` because you have updated that column?

Comment: I've edited it with an example. Please review and let me know if I understood your requirement correctly

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, that's what I needed. For future readers, I wanted to express the question in more general form. But anyways, you know better. Thank you

Comment: Would `UPDATE [dbo].[Customer]  
set ShipMethodRef = ShipMethod.ShipMethodID
OUTPUT ShipMethod.Name as ShipMethodName
FROM [dbo].[Customer] curTable 
JOIN [dbo].ShipMethod ShipMethod ON 21 = ShipMethod.ShipMethodID
WHERE CustomerID=5497;` work for you?

Comment: Generally it works. But in this case, I simplified the question. To get the Id, I use the next construct: ShipMethodRef = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ShipMethodID from [dbo].[ShipMethod] WHERE [dbo].[ShipMethod].Name = ?) THEN (SELECT ShipMethodID from [dbo].[ShipMethod] WHERE [dbo].[ShipMethod].Name = ?) ELSE curTable.ShipMethodRef END. So actually get the Id by Name of ShipMethod, if such ShipMethod exists. I set by name, and I want the updated Name back. If there is no such method, I don't update at all. And how to embed it to your solution (it's great though!) - I don't know currently

Comment: And all this I want to do atomically. If that's too complex, probably I should use MERGE or something?

Comment: I think, you need to use `INSERTED`. During update you have deleted and inserted value. `OUTPUT INSERTED ShipMethod.Name as ShipMethodName` will give you new value

Comment: @T.S. - the table being updated doesn't contain that column. It just has an Id that is mapped to the name through a lookup to another table

Comment: @MartinSmith ah, I see. Was your solution even possible?

Comment: I've updated: ShipMethodRef has conditional assignment. By now the question was changed significantly with the help of Martin Smith, but still it has downvotes. Could the guys who downvoted it restore it back? It can be helpful for future readers

Comment: I don't think this can be done with a single statement except in the way Martin showed in his previous comment, but you can get the output from inserted into a table variable or a temporary table and then select from that joined to the translation tables.

Comment: @Zohar Thank you. If it's not possible you may post your comment as the answer. The only reason I wanted to run it in single statement is to make it atomic. For this I would use BEGIN TRANSACTION - COMMIT or think of locking then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with a single statement except in the way Martin showed in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59501747/how-to-get-a-column-derived-from-joining-on-inserted-value/59532887#comment105176325_59501747), but you can get the output from inserted into a table variable or a temporary table and then select from that joined to the translation tables.
Here's how I would do that (note the update statement is simplified):

```
DECLARE @UpdatedIds AS TABLE (ShipMethodID int);

UPDATE [dbo].[Customer]  
SET ShipMethodRef = COALESCE((
        SELECT ShipMethodID 
        FROM [dbo].[ShipMethod] 
        WHERE [dbo].[ShipMethod].Name = 'UPS'    
    ), ShipMethodRef)
OUTPUT inserted.ShipMethodRef INTO @UpdatedIds
FROM [dbo].[Customer] 
WHERE CustomerID=5497;

SELECT SM.ShipMethodID, SM.Name
FROM [dbo].ShipMethod AS SM
JOIN @UpdatedIds AS Updated
    ON SM.ShipMethodID = Updated.ShipMethodID
```

Comment: shalom! My question has been edited 5 times, still, it has -3 votes as if it wasn't totally rewritten and polished. Recently it was downvoted again... What is the purpose for me to keep the question and what benefit do I have from it now?

Comment: Why are you asking me? I didn't downvote your question, and I also can't tell what *you* get from it after you've already got the answer.... I'm not sure SO will let you delete it since it has an upvoted answer - but I would advise you to think about it as a contribution to your fellow developers (and in fact, on any stackoverflow post for that matter). Someday, some other dev will face the same problem and maybe, just maybe they will see your question and it's answer and benefit from it. Perhaps they'll even upvote the question and/or the answer.